# rospy.init_node in multiprocessing.Process

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-kinetic, rospy, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have the following setup:

- The main thread which starts a ROS node with services, pubs, and subs
- A multiprocessing.Process which also should start an (anonymous) ROS node that has pubs and subs

So far so good. When I start (fork) the new process before calling rospy.init_node, everything works fine when I start from the command line.

However, when I start the application via roslaunch, I get the following error:

> shutdown request: new node registered with same name

It looks like roslaunch/node enforces a new name in every node started as a subprocess. Any ideas how to circumvent the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297918/rospy.init_node-in-multiprocessing.process/) by [machinekoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/33820/machinekoder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2018-07-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [machinekoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/33820/machinekoder/) on 2018-07-19**:
I found the culprit: https://github.com/strawlab/ros_comm/blob/master/clients/rospy/src/rospy/client.py#L223
Looks like the name mappings override even anonymous nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a workaround:

```
try:
    del rospy.names.get_mappings()['__name']
except KeyError:
    pass
```

However, I would prefer if rospy would have an option to force anonymity.

---

Originally posted by [machinekoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/33820/machinekoder/) with karma: 69 on 2018-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1